# Copy and Pasting Specific Values From A Selected Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am looking to copy a specific set of cells from a selected workbook using a browse prompt. In the code below I can get the macro to successfully run however when the macro finishes running the values from the selected cells do not appear in the active workbook. I do not get any errors when the macro runs, however I also do not see the values in the active workbook. Any suggestions? The code is listed below.

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
wb1.Worksheets("Template").Unprotect Password:="cna"

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose Exsiting PO Template", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Else

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
    wb2.Worksheets("Template").Unprotect Password:="cna"
    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A4").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A4").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues


    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B4").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B4").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C4").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C4").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D4").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D4").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A7").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B7").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C7").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D7").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E7").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With



    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F7").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A10").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A10").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B10").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B10").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C10").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C10").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D10").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D10").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E10").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E10").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F10").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F10").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("G10").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("G10").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("I10").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("I10").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A13").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A13").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B13").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B13").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A19").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B19").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C19").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F19").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("G19").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("G19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End With
    End With


    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A26").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B26").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C26").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D26").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E26").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F26").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("G26").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("G26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("H26").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("H26").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A29").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A29").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B29").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B29").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C29").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C29").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D29").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D29").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E29").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E29").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F29").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F29").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A32").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("A32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B32").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("B32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C32").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("C32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D32").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("D32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E32").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("E32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F32").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("F32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("G32").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("G32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        Range("H32").Select
        Selection.Copy
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        Range("H32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
    End With


End If

wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **dots(.)** missing inside the **with**

```
With wb2.Sheets("Template")
        .Range("A4").Copy ' missing . operator in the beginning
    With wb1.Sheets("Template")
        .Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlValues 'also try to avoid .select in your code -it will slow down your code
 end with
    End With
```

Comment: You're amazing. I took out the select functions and added the dots (.) Thank you for the quick response!